# how can i merge two field in combobox

Tags: c#, sql-server, combobox

**this is my code :**

```
cmbSahebFa.Items.Clear();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "select mID,mName from tblMoshtari";
        objCon.Connecting();
        cmd.Connection = objCon.con;
        objCon.con.Open();
        try
        {
            SqlDataReader objDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            object[] x = new object[2];
            while (objDataReader.Read())
            {
                objDataReader.GetSqlValues(x);
                cmbSahebFa.Items.Add(x[1].ToString());

            }
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error") :  " + exp.Message);
        }
        finally
        {

            objCon.con.Close();
        }
```

i want to display both field in combo box.
**how can i show two field mID+mName in combobox ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cmbSahebFa.Items.Add(objDataReader[0].ToString() + " " + objDataReader[1].ToString());
```

or

```
SqlDataReader objDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
object[] x = new object[2];
while (objDataReader.Read())
{
     objDataReader.GetSqlValues(x);
     cmbSahebFa.Items.Add(x[0].ToString()+ " " + x[1].ToString());
}
```

or by column name

```
SqlDataReader objDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (objDataReader.Read())
{                
   cmbSahebFa.Items.Add(objDataReader["mID"].ToString() + " " + objDataReader["mName"].ToString());
}
```

Here is MSDN Reference on [Retrieving Data Using DataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I think, SQL concatination would be easier:

```
cmd.CommandText = "select mID + ' ' + mName from tblMoshtari";
```